# Nuxt3 click event issue

Tags: vuejs3, click, nuxt3

I am facing the issue of the click event. In my project, I have a language change option, and I have functionality that shows images with full size when clicked on it.
When the language is changed to German from English, my click event is not working.
In English, it is working correctly, so I am not getting what the cause of the issue is. I didn't even get any errors in the log.
Here is my code snippet for your reference:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const handleClick = (index: any) => {
  console.log('clicked');
} 
const getStyle(index:any){
  console.log('getStyle'); 
} 
</script>
```

Here, after the language change, I am not getting any logs of my handleClick function.

1. I have tried to use **@click.native**
2. I have tries to **clear site data** and then retry but it didn't worked.
3. I have also tried using **npm run build**, when build successfully run below command again
   **npm run dev**.